# Rotate a Image to MousePos?

Tags: java, image, rotation

I want to rotate an Image in java, initialized with

```
            playerimage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:/Game/player.png"); //Load Player Image
```

drawed with:

```
        Graphics2D g = buffer.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(playerimage, player.getX(), player.getY(), null); // Draw Player
```

Now, I want my playerimage, to rotate to my mouse, so it's basically looking to my mouse. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you want it to *always* face exactly toward the mouse, or do you want it to turn toward the mouse at a limited rate, so that if the player moves the mouse too fast, it takes the image a moment to "catch up"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is get both the mouse pos and the player pos in the same coord system.  When you get our mouse pos it will normally be in Screen Coords while your player maybe in your own 'World Coords' space.  If the players position is tied directly to pixels then you can skip ahead.

Convert the Mouse Position to World coords..

```
mouseWorld.X = (mouseScreen.X / screenWidth) * worldWidth;
```

Once you are in the same coord system you need to find the angle required to rotate.  This equation will change based on which way your Player art is facing, lets assume it is facing up the position X axis.  Then you can just use the dot product to find the angle between where your player is facing and where the point is pointing.

```
The dot product is A(dot)B = mag(A) * mag(B) * cos (theta) 
mag = magnitude of the vector
theta = angle between the two vectors
So if you normalize the vectors (make them length 1) then..
A(dot)B = 1 * 1 * cos(theta)
A(dot)B = cos(theta)
acos(A(dot)B) = theta
```

So lets do code...

```
Vector mouseVec(mouseWorld.X, mouseWorld.Y);
Vector playerVec(playerWorld.X, playerWorld.Y);

//You want to find the angle the player must turn, so pretend the player pos it the origin
mouseVec -= playerVec;

//Create a vector that represents which way your player art is facing
Vector facingVec(1, 0);

mouseVec.Normalize();  //Make their length 1
facingVec.Normalize();

double dotProd = mouseVec.dot(facing);
double angBetween = acos(dotProd);
```

then call 'rotate' and pass in the angBetween!

Double check that the units are correct, often acos will return 'radians' and the rotate function will take 'degrees' so you need to convert.

More vector info:
[Vector Info](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/33design/Vector.java.html)

Comment: Okay so, I just started Java, and I really have no idea what's going on in this code, and how to use it, I've never really worked with Vectors before yet.

Comment: The `java.util.Vector` class you used in your code example is *not* the `Vector` class that you linked to.  Java's `Vector` is a list, not a geometric vector; you can't construct one with X and Y coordinates, and it has no `Normalize()` method.

Comment: @Wyzard - Oops, good catch.  See the vector class linked in 'Vector Info' at the bottom.

Comment: @Stan - Well as Wyzard pointed out I was using the wrong Vector so I am sure that didn't help.  A Vector is a Math/Physics term for a container that holds a set of coordinates.  You can think of it like an arrow that starts at 0, 0 and points towards those coordinates.  The code I have here creates 2 vectors from your positions.  Then uses the Dot Product (an operation like multiplication or Subtraction that can be performed on vectors) to find the angle between those vectors.  You can then rotate your player image by that amount.